# React-router: scroll restoration doesn't work

Tags: reactjs, scroll, react-router, use-effect

I'm trying to restore the scroll position back to the top of the page when I change the url path but it doesn't work.
I created a ScrollToTop component, with a useEffect() that is supposed to react to the path change. Then I imported the component into my routing but nothing changed and I don't understand why. Do you have any idea / advice ?

ScrollToTop component:

```
import { useLocation } from "react-router-dom";

export default function ScrollToTop() {
  const { pathname } = useLocation();

  useEffect(() => {
    window.scrollTo(0, 0);
  }, [pathname]);

  return null;
}
```

App.js:

```
...
import {
  BrowserRouter as Router,
  Switch,
  Route,
} from "react-router-dom"
import ScrollToTop from "./components/ScrollToTop"

function App() {
  return (
       <Router>
       <ScrollToTop />
        <Header></Header>
        <Switch>
          <Route path="/about">
            <About/>
          </Route>
          <Route path="/works">
            <Works />
          </Route>
          <Route path="/">
            <Home />
          </Route>
        </Switch>
        <Footer></Footer>
      </Router>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: It looks like it should be working, could you make a reproducible example on codepen or similar?

Answer (score 0):

You should use `ScrollToTop` component to every routed page. Or pass props from `App` component. Because, App is mounted only once. For this, `pathname` changes but, it does not effect the ui. You may use like this:

**App.js**

```
import {
  BrowserRouter as Router,
  Switch,
  Route,
  useLocation
} from "react-router-dom"
import ScrollToTop from "./components/ScrollToTop"

function App() {
  const { pathname } = useLocation();

  return (
       <Router>
       <ScrollToTop pathName={pathname} />
        <Header></Header>
        <Switch>
          <Route path="/about">
            <About/>
          </Route>
          <Route path="/works">
            <Works />
          </Route>
          <Route path="/">
            <Home />
          </Route>
        </Switch>
        <Footer></Footer>
      </Router>
  );
}

export default App;
```

**ScrollToTop.js**

```
export default function ScrollToTop(pathName) {
  useEffect(() => {
    window.scrollTo(0, 0);
  }, [pathName]);

  return null;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer but it still doesn't work. I got this error : `Cannot read property 'location' of undefined`
I also tried to use the component in every routed page and the scroll doesn't go to the top of the page